# Replacing characters by a modified version of them in a string

Tags: c++, regex, replace

I want to replace the characters below (or sub-strings for the && and ||)in an input string with regex replace

```
+ - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ && ||
```

How can I write this request in the construction of the std::regex ?

For example if I have

```
"(1+1):2"
```

I want to have an input of :

```
"\(1\+1\)\:2"
```

The final code looks something like this :

```
  std::string s ("(1+1):2");
  std::regex e ("???");   // what should I put here ?

  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"\\$2"); // is this correct ?
```

Comment: `std::regex_replace("(1+1):2", regex("[-+!\"\\[\\](){}^~*?:]|&&|\\|\\|"), "\\$0");`

Comment: @revo Thanks it works too, but what's the difference with the answer below ?

Comment: The difference is it's shorter and much more efficient since it benefits from a character class.

Comment: @revo You should write this as an answer, I think.

Comment: @revo what does $0 mean please ? is the tube (|) used as an OR operator ? are double backslashes (in fact one backslah) used to escape some special characters in the regex (tube |) ? Thanks

Comment: `$0` refers to entire current match. A pipe `|` in a regex opens another path in case of failure for engine to try it out that you can call it OR operator. Yes, in C++ regex, all meta-characters should be double escaped in order to represent a literal character.

Comment: @revo Thanks ! last question about the dollar char $, I've seen $2 in a code (here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) so why 2 ?

Comment: All replacement strings with special meaning in ECMAScript flavor (which `std::regex` supports it) start with a dollar sign. You could see `$$` as a feature. You can use a single `$` to represent one literal dollar sign but if you need more in a row you should choose another alternative. E.g. `$$$$` or `\$\$`

Comment: @revo Hi revo, can you please see my new question related to this regex_replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680398/weird-results-of-stdregex-replace-under-vs2015 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) with capture:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex regex_a("(\\+|-|!|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|\\^|\"|~|\\*|\\?|:|\\\\|&&|\\|\\|)");
    cout << regex_replace("(1+1):2", regex_a, "\\$0") << endl;
}
```

This prints

```
$ ./a.out 
\(1\+1\)\:2
```

Comment: @Aminos I basically learned regex in Python using the documentation of its standard library. It's pretty much the same in all languages. What's the language with which you're most comfortable?

Comment: C++ is the language I use the most.

Comment: @Aminos Well, IMHO C++ documentation, in general, tends to spoon-feed a bit less than most other languages (and I *like* being spoon fed!). However, if C++ it is, looking around for it, personally, I'd try the following (hope this isn't misleading you): I'd read the documentation of [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), which seems pretty comprehensive, and take into account that the `std` regex library might be a tad different. Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: `[|]` denotes a literal `|` not `[` and `]` characters.