# Referring to whole match from replacement pattern using std::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2015

The code below doesn't give the same result in Visual Studio 2015 and IDEOne.com (C++14). More strange, in both cases the results are incorrect !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   const char* pszTestString = "ENDRESS+HAUSER*ST-DELL!HP||BESTMATCH&&ABCD\\ABCD";
   const char* pszExpectedString = "ENDRESS\\+HAUSER\\*ST\\-DELL\\!HP\\||BESTMATCH\\&&ABCD\\\\ABCD";
   std::cout << std::regex_replace(pszTestString, std::regex("[-+!\"\\[\\](){}^~*?:]|&&|\\|\\|"), "\\$0") << std::endl;
   std::cout << pszExpectedString << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Under Visual Studio 2015 I got this strange result, the second line contains the expected result for both compilers :

```
ENDRESS\$0HAUSER\$0ST\$0DELL\$0HP\$0BESTMATCH\$0ABCD\ABCD
ENDRESS\+HAUSER\*ST\-DELL\!HP\||BESTMATCH\&&ABCD\\ABCD
```

With IDEOne (C++14 compiler) :

```
ENDRESS\+HAUSER\*ST\-DELL\!HP\||BESTMATCH\&&ABCD\ABCD
ENDRESS\+HAUSER\*ST\-DELL\!HP\||BESTMATCH\&&ABCD\\ABCD
```

We can see in the latter that there is a mistake : before the last "ABCD" there must be two backslashes and not a single one

What the heck is going on ? I wrote a manual parser instead of using std::regex_replace for the moment, but I really want make it work under VS2015 (and any other IDE ideally) and make a benchmark before choosing the manual parsing solution.

Comment: Do everyone who's reading this a favor: cut your test string back to the shortest one you can come up with that still shows the problem, and remove extraneous parts from the regular expression (most of the characters inside the `[]` aren't in the target string, so they just make the regular expression harder to read).

Comment: To match a ``\`` you should first add it to your character class: `[-+!\\\\\"\\[\\](){}^~*?:]|&&|\\|\\|`.

Comment: @revo Thank you for everything ! it's clear now

Comment: BTW : manually parsing the string (with a loop and a switch for example) is much more faster than using std::/boost::regex_replace ! Thank you all for helping me achieve my benchmark !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2015 default compiler does not treat `$0` as a zeroth backreference. **You need to use the ["native" ECMAScript `$&` backreference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) to refer to the whole match from inside the replacement pattern.**

Also, [revo is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680398/weird-results-of-stdregex-replace-under-vs2015/39681183#comment66661428_39680398), in order to match `\` you need to add it to the character class.

And note that in VS2015 you can use raw string literals. It is best practice to use raw string literals to define regex patterns as they help avoid *overescaping* (also called as [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/)).

Solution:

```
std::cout << std::regex_replace(pszTestString, 
      std::regex(R"([-+!\\\"\[\](){}^~*?:]|&&|\|\|)"), "\\$&") << std::endl;
                        ^^                                ^^
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now ! but I wonder why have you prefixed the regex with an 'R' ?

Comment: UPDATE : Ah OK, apparently "R" it means row, isn't it ? so you don't have to escape backslahes in the literal... thus avoiding what you call backslash hell :D

Comment: Well, I mentioned that *in VS2015 you can use raw string literals*, and that is exactly the what the `R"()"` is for - to define a raw string literal. The `\\` before `\"` define a literal backslash in the character class.